# Yii2 - How to use attributes with dash (-) in the name

Tags: yii2

I am trying to generate active form field by using

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
...
<?= $form->field($competitor, 't-shirt_size' )->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

which gives me the following error

```
Attribute name must contain word characters only.
```

The field name in the database is `t-shirt_size`

Answer (score 0):

You see this error because of the way ActiveRecord pattern works.

Explanation for this can be found in the [Yii 2 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#accessing-data).

> Because Active Record attributes are **named after table columns**, you may find you are writing PHP code like `$customer->first_name`, which uses underscores to separate words in attribute names if your table columns are named in this way. If you are concerned about code style consistency, you should rename your table columns accordingly (to use camelCase, for example).

In PHP you can not create object attribute with dash in its name so DB column name with dash, despite being allowed in some DB engines, would not be available as ActiveRecord attribute.

You have to rename the DB field or use something else than ActiveForm widget to generate the form although I'm not sure if you will not hit an exception regarding this attribute somewhere else.

Comment: I had some problems using this field in `DetailView`. If i try to use it directly `'t-shirt_size',` there was the same error. But if i use it `[ 'attribute' => 't-shirt_size', ],` there is no error. This is the reason for me to look for solution for the problem. @Bizley